# Missing /var/www Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, sftp

I found [a guide on enabling SFTP on Ubuntu](http://kpdirection.com/technology/setting-up-sftp-on-ubuntu/) and it mentions the directory `/var/www`. So I checked my `/var` directory and it wasn't there. I saw evidence that it could be in a different folder so I used `locate /*/www` but the output was `bashie@tinylinbook:/srv$ locate /*/www
bashie@tinylinbook:/srv$` ; nothing. Do I need this directory or will SFTP sort itself out? I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give access to user's web directory you need a web root directory. Do you have apache or another web server install on your system? If so, check is configuration and change */var/www* in your sftp configuration for the web root server path. If you want to install a web server check this [tutorial about LAMP installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

If you don't want web server and you just want to connect to your system through sftp you can check [this tutorial](http://yetanothercomputingblog.blogspot.ca/2012/05/ubuntu-setup-sftp-server.html)

Comment: Never mind, I tried a different SFTP client (WinSCP) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

/var/www/ has nothing to do with shhd, it's for web servers.

You can install Apache or nginx if you want a httpd, but as I say, it's completely unnecessary for ssh and sftp.

The guide you're following is geared at giving each user their own website and limiting them to it.

Comment: Thank you. So could I use any directory for this then?

Comment: Yeah. Most people would use /home/...